# Extracting information from gradle file with regex

Tags: java, regex, gradle

I have a text file(scriptdocument.txt) as follows:

```
// Files 
File 'de.package.files.func:Lib1:1.1.1:32-bit@trs' 
File 'de.package.files.func:Lib2:1.3.6:64-bit@trs' 
File 'de.package.files.func:Lib3:1.+:lib@trs' 
File 'de.package.files.func:Lib4:1.+:lib@trs'
```

I am only interested in extracting the information aftr the second ':' till '@'
ie: the number associated in each line for each lib
eg: lib1 version is 1.1.1:32-bit
and   lib2 version is 1.3.6:64-bit

So I make use of the regex in the gradle file as follows:

```
File file = new File("scriptdocument.txt")
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(file)

def line, lineNumber = 0
while(fileScanner.hasNextLine()){
    if(lineNumber!=0){
        line = fileScanner.nextLine()
        def regex = /(.+?):(.+?):(.+?)@trs/ //throws an error
        def match = $line =~regex   //throws an error


    }
    lineNumber++
}
fileScanner.close()
```

I want the matches to be stored in the list, so that I can use them.. I observed that the regex shows a match on the regex101.com. Attached is the snapshot[image: regex]

Any help with the gradle script would be helpful. Looking forward for some suggestions

Comment: If you still need help, could you please create a live online demo/fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't JavaScript and  I'm not certain if this is Java, because there's also Groovy keywords.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(.+?):(.+?):(.+?)@trs").matcher($line);
ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
while (m.find()) {matches.add(m.group(0));}
```

In short: don't mix up three languages, but stick with one.

Comment: Its groovy, similar to java